# getSystemService() is not defined

Tags: android, service

I am trying to create the below posted method to check if a service is running or not. but getSystemService() is markd with red because it is not defined
and it needs a context. I used the following:

```
Application.getContext().getSystemService
```

but still getContext is not defined.

in the code i do the following:

```
if (ServicesUtils.isServiceRunning(NonStickyService.class.getSimpleName())) {
        Log.i(TAG, "++++++++++ SERVICE IS RUNNING +++++++++");
} else {
        Log.i(TAG, "++++++++++ SERVICE IS NOT RUNNING +++++++++");
}
```

please let me know which context i should use.

**code1**:

```
public class ServicesUtils {
private static String LOG_TAG = ServicesUtils.class.getName();

public static boolean isServiceRunning(String serviceClassName) {
    final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> services = activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo runningServiceInfo : services) {
        if (runningServiceInfo.service.getClassName().equals(serviceClassName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

**code2**:

```
public class App extends Application {

public static com.example.pc_amr.stickyvsnonstickyservice.App instance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    instance = this;
}

public static com.example.pc_amr.stickyvsnonstickyservice.App getInstance() {
    return instance;
} // get the instance
}
```

Comment: Since `getSystemService` is the part of the `Context`.And your class has no relation to context. So you have to make an Object of the Context  and then you can use context.getSystemService.And make sure to pass the value of context using constructor to avoid NPE.

Comment: How can you assign an `App` object to a `Context` object in `instance = this`?

Answer (score 1):

Since `getSystemService` is the part of the `Context`. And your `class` has no relation to `context`. So you have to make an Object of the `Context` and then you can use `context.getSystemService`.And make sure to pass the value of `context` using a `constructor` to avoid `NPE`.

You can do something like this

`public static boolean isServiceRunning(String serviceClassName,Context context) {
        final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);`

Comment: it does not work...i updated the question ..please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try **creating a static instance** of your `Application` class:

```
public class App extends Application {

    public static App instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }

    public static App getInstance() { return instance; } // get the instance
}
```

Now if you need context you can simply use `App.getInstance()`. As we know Application class extends Context.
**Remember to register App class**

Comment: it does not work...i updated the question ..please have a look.

Comment: in `isServiceRunning` replace `getSystemService` with `App.getInstance().getSystemService(..)`